# how to remove 2 additional last chars that printf cmd adds in bash script?

Tags: find

I got a command line that searches for all file names that end with ".sh" in
the cur dir and all subdirs. It should display only the name of files without the extension .sh.

```
find -type f \( -name "*.sh" \) -printf "%f\n"
```

somehow this gives me files with names ending with "double" .sh . For example:

this is expected:

```
"P.shn.sh", "JEr.shyiIr.shXL", ".shHmIwzJ.sh.sh", "S.sh.sh.shVG.sh"
```

this is what i get:

```
"P.shn.sh.sh", "JEr.shyiIr.shXL.sh", ".shHmIwzJ.sh.sh.sh", "S.sh.sh.shVG.sh.sh"
```

I suspect printf adds ".sh" but how? I actually want to avoid printf, i can use sed,awk.

or I can trim the last 2 chars "sh". the problem is - how to pipe the output of printf to awk, if awk(or sed) needs the output to be declared as var? 
but i need it all in one line.

not like this:

```
$output    =  find -type f \( -name "*.sh" \) -printf "%f\n"
'awk {output , print$1}'
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, are you sure those filenames don't actually have double .sh at the end? And is this a Windows environment?

Comment: @oguzismail it's actually online ide where tests are run.

Comment: Sounds like your IDE is broken in this regard. I wonder in what other ways it's giving you incorrect output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pretty and simply solution :

```
find ./whatEverDir -type f -name "*.sh" -exec bash -c '
for file; do
    echo "${file%.*}"
done
' bash {} +
```

one line version :

```
find ./test -name "*.sh" -exec bash -c 'for file; do echo "${file%.*}";done ' bash {} +
```

input :

```
./test/.shHmIwzJ.sh.sh
./test/S.sh.sh.shVG.sh.sh
./test/P.shn.sh.sh
./test/JEr.shyiIr.shXL.sh
./test/.shHmIwzJ.sh.sh.sh
```

output :

```
./test/.shHmIwzJ.sh
./test/S.sh.sh.shVG.sh
./test/P.shn.sh
./test/JEr.shyiIr.shXL
./test/.shHmIwzJ.sh.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type f -name "*.sh"  -printf "%f\n"  | rev | cut -c 4- | rev
```

this worked fine as well